# What's the purpose in the "Morning after" mission?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In Saints row the third, I finished grabbing control of the Stanfield district, which triggers the "The Morning After" mission.

However, for some reason, there are no markers or anything on my map, and the dialogue is not very revealing either. What is the purpose of the mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this mission's article on the [wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Morning_After), there is no purpose to this mission. It's just one of those funny little things.